# how to make maven use test resources

Tags: java, testing, maven

when I use the command: mvn test, maven uses the main resources instead of the test ones in src/test/resources.

How can i make maven use the test resources rather than the main resources?

EDIT: I use Classloader to find my resources. Classloader can find resources from my src/test/resources directory, but it looks in src/main/java first for the resource.

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream file =loader.getResourceAsStream("resource.xml");
```

Or is there any property I can use while running a maven command that will prioritize a classpath?

EDIT 2: I have figured out the problem, it does load from test/resources for the test, however my test involves deploying a webapp (integration testing) and from there when the webapp accesses the resource it uses src/main/resources. Is there a way to change the order of the classpath or make one precede the other for a WAR deployed in a jetty container?

Comment: please don't ask the same question again, edit your existing question with any relevant updates instead which will give your question a bump. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you give it another name ? 
 The Loader doesn't know that your **resource.xml** is in `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`, it's only a path to look for. I think the problem it's not Maven, this is how the Loader should and it works. From Maven would you expect to discard all **classes/resources** from `src/main/resources` when doing the test phase ?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe you can configure surefire or load the resource manually in your test class.

Comment: I have figured out the problem, it does load from test/resources for the test, however my test involves deploying a webapp (integration testing) and from there when the webapp accesses the resource it uses src/main/resources. Is there a way to change the order of the classpath or make one precede the other for a WAR deployed in a jetty container? I will update my question

Answer (score 6):

Please check your **target/test-classes** directory for **resource.xml**. 
Your file should be here. If you find this file, I think the same name is the problem. Try rename the file for example to test-resource.xml. If the file doesn't exists in the test-classes directory, you should configure resource management in the maven pom.xml. Use [maven-resouce-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/).
Hope it helps.