# Maven is not using test resources while testing

Tags: java, maven, classpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make maven use test resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267312/how-to-make-maven-use-test-resources)

I have a resource "resource.xml" in both src/main/resources and src/test/resources. While running tests from maven, the resource from src/main/resources takes precedence over src/test/resources. How can i make it so that it uses the resource from src/test/resources instead?

I use ClassLoader to get the resource:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream file =loader.getResourceAsStream("resource.xml");
```

EDIT: I have figured out the problem, it does load from test/resources for the test, however my test involves deploying a webapp (integration testing) and from there when the webapp accesses the resource it uses src/main/resources. Is there a way to change the order of the classpath or make one precede the other for a WAR deployed in a jetty container?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267312/how-to-make-maven-use-test-resources