# Failed to load ApplicationContext for JUnit test of Spring controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, junit4, spring-mvc-test

I want to write a test case to check my controller (getPersons). This is a server side code. I have confusion what should i put inside `@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/app-contest.xml"})`

Secondly, I'm getting some errors like this:

> Failed to load application context. Can not find the path [which I specified in @ContextConfiguration]

I have a structure like this:

```
 restAPI
    *src/main/java
      com.company.controller
         personController.java
    *Test
      com.company.testController
         personControllerTest.java
    *src
      main
       webapp
         WEBINF
           app-context.xml


@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

@RequestMapping(value="/t2/{yy_id}/person", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public PersonInfo[] getPersons() {

    return personService.getPersons();
}
```

---

This is my Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:WEB-INF/app-context.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class PersonControllerTest  {


@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

@Test
public void getPersons() throws Exception {

    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/t2/1/person")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

---

Trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:157)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:313)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.GenericXmlWebContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(GenericXmlWebContextLoader.java:38)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:113)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:59)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/app-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
```

Can some one please help me out to figure it out what's wrong here?

Comment: I think that `WEB-INF` location should be loaded via `file:/WEB-INF/...` and not `classpath:WEB-INF`.

Comment: I have tried file as well still I'm getting the same eror

Comment: Are you sure it is not a spelling error? app-context.xml instead of app-contest.xml ;o

Comment: here in the question i have written by mistake contest but in my application it is context but its not working

Comment: Any chance you will post the actual exception / error with a stack trace?

Comment: I have post the actual stack trace so please suggest me something

Comment: With a similar structure, `@ContextConfiguration(locations = "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/app-context.xml")` works for me. My test file is under src/test/java/com/company/** whereas yours seems to be under `Test` which is parallel to `src`

Answer (score 28):

As mentioned in the discussion: `WEB-INF` is not really part of the class path. If you use a common template, such as maven, use `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources` to place the `app-context.xml` in. Then you can use `classpath:`.

Place your config file in `src/main/resources/app-context.xml` and use the following code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:app-context.xml")
public class PersonControllerTest {
  ...
}
```

You can also create your test context with different configurations of beans.

Place your config file into `src/test/resources/test-app-context.xml` and use:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:test-app-context.xml")
public class PersonControllerTest {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using maven also in the project

Comment: Ok, I've edited and enhance my answer, so now you can apply it in your project, @Saurabh.

Comment: In the first case you mentioned, you placed the app-context.xml file in src/main/resources. But when you run tests, it will not find it there, but src/test/resources. So where should it be placed for unit tests?

Comment: Both src/test/* and src/main/* are present in the test phase of maven lifecycle if your POM is correct. Also you can change many thinks in maven. I rather use test-app-context.xml for testing and app-context.xml to separate their usage and content. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267312/how-to-make-maven-use-test-resources and http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: My project do not have app-context.xml file. Only spring-servelt.xml and web.xml file.please help me how to solve the issue.

Comment: I guess in your project file spring-servelt.xml is the spring context definition as well app-context.xml in the question.

Comment: @ContextConfiguration("classpath*:**/applicationContext.xml") worked for me.

Comment: I am not using xml, how do I do?

Comment: If you use Java based Spring configuration I would suggest to ask a new question, because the answer is slightly different and would be hard to mix with this question/answer.

Answer (score 13):

There can be multiple root causes for this exception. For me, my mockMvc wasn't getting auto-configured. I solved this exception by using `@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)` at the class level. This annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MVC tests.

An alternative to this is, If you are looking to load your full application configuration and use MockMVC, you should consider `@SpringBootTest` combined with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` rather than `@WebMvcTest`

Comment: WebMvcTest(MyController.class) didn't work for me. But the alternate solution of adding SpringBootTest and AutoConfigureMockMvc worked me. Thanks.

Comment: thanks this worked for me bones tip , add @WithMockUser above the testing method or other wise the response will be 401 , unauthorized

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Maven, add the below config in your pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <testResources>
                <testResource>
                    <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                </testResource>
    </testResources>
</build>
```

With this config, you will be able to access xml files in WEB-INF folder.
From Maven POM Reference:
The testResources element block contains testResource elements. Their definitions are similar to resource elements, but are naturally used during test phases.

Answer (score 4):

In case you landed here based on the title, desperate for a solution and happen to be using Junit 5 Jupiter, you need to use

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
```

instead of

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with Junit5:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class},
        webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT,
        properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false"})
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

Answer (score 1):

Sovled by editing the annotation

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using same version of spring boot and spring cloud dependency works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue after migrating to Junit 5 from Junit4.

For me this resolved the issue -

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml" })
```

in

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.config.location=classpath:application-test.yml" })
class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

where `application-test.yml` is located under `src/test/resources`

you also need to add this to `@ActiveProfiles("test")` all your test classes since I am using `test` profile (application-**test**.yml).

Answer (score -7):

Solved by adding the following dependency into pom.xml file :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```